# Convert custom json payload to something Ember Data understands?

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

So we're making an app with a rest-y json http api. How the server returns it's data is beyond my reach, and it is not in a way compatible with Ember Data's assumptions.

How do you configure RESTAdapter to convert the payload? What is the correct part of the DS api to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so found this out. The Ember

Make a custom `RESTSerializer`:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractArray: function () {
    // Your custom magick
  },
  extractSingle: function () {
    // You wizardry for when single objects are returned
  }
});
```